# Finding probability mass function $f(x)$

Tags: probability

The question given is:

[image]

---

What I do not understand is how do I get the last line of the image:

$$f(x) = \sum_{y=x}^\infty 
\underbrace{\left(
\begin{array}{c}
y \\
x
\end{array}
\right)
p^x(1-p)^{y-x}}_{1st}
\,\,
\underbrace{\frac{\lambda^y e^{-\lambda}}{y!}}_{2nd}
$$

The 1st part seems to be something to do with probability of getting $x$, and 2nd getting $y$ (, but not really)?

What I know is

$$f(x) = \sum_y f(x, y)$$

But is $f(x, y) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
y \\
x
\end{array}
\right)
p^x(1-p)^{y-x}
\,\,
\frac{\lambda^y e^{-\lambda}}{y!}$?

If so it looks kind of like $f(x) = f(x) f(y)$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said it correctly. Since $f(x,y)=f(x|y)f(y)$ and given that $X|Y=y$ is binomial and $Y$ is Poisson, you should just multiply their density functions, right?

Answer (score 1):

$f(x,y)=f(x|y)f(y)$ as in what "we have"

What you are dealing with is $$Pr(X=x) = \sum_y Pr(X=x, Y=y) = \sum_y Pr(X=x|Y=y) Pr(Y=y)$$ taken from the first line of the question where $X|Y=y$ has a binomial distribution and $Y$ has a Poisson distribution.

Answer (score 0):

This uses the (Bayes) formula $f(x)=\sum\limits_yf(x\mid y)f(y)$. Your suggestion amounts to say that $f(x)=\sum\limits_yf(x,y)f(y)$, which is obviously wrong.

Answer (score 0):

This uses Bayes formula as suggested about which is $$f(x) = \frac{f(y)f(x|y)}{f(y|x)}.$$ In the example it provide that fact that the random variable $Y$ has a Poisson distribution and that the conditional random variable $X|Y$ has a binomial distribution. The summation follows because we are talking about a discrete space.

Comment: No, the solution does not use this Bayes formula. In fact to compute f(x) through this formula would be odd since one does not know f(y|x) (one is looking for it).